# Regex for my query string matches only one value

Tags: regex, query-string, pcre

Help me please to create good regex. I have such a string:
`'text&variable=tekst2&categories=metal;wood&author:elvis;arnold'`
I need to retrieve all categories as separated strings so the result should be 2 strings: `'metal'` and `'wood'`.
If it was three or four categories the result should be three or four separated strings.

I created my reges but it gave only one string.

```
/(?<=&categories=).*?([^;&]+)/
```

The online demo is there:
https://regex101.com/r/G6pRUQ/2

How to get the regex that would give all categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PCRE regex to match categories as several matches, use

```
(?:\G(?!\A);*|[&?]categories=)\K[^;&]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6pRUQ/4).

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A);*|[&?]categories=)` - match `&` or `?`, `categories=`, or the end of the previous successful match and 0+ semi-colons
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `[^;&]+` - 1 or more chars other than  `;` and `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language you are using but in Java I would go for following code:

```
String str = "text&variable=tekst2&categories=metal;wood&author:elvis;arnold";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&categories=(.*?)&");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher();
ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()){
    categories.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Please check for syntax of the language you are using. But basic logic will be similar to above.